# There goes my buzz - meaning?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'm watching **'Into The Badlands'** *(Season 3, episode 7, timestamp: 21:00--)* and I came across a sentence I've never heard before. I would like to know its meaning.

**Background:** Sunny went to find the other survivor of the massacre happened in the boat when Sunny was a child. Finally, he found the place of that old man. The conversation between them is below:
Sunny: You're a hard man to find.
Old man: Are you here to kill me?
Sunny: The River King sent me. I'm here to talk. 
Old man: Suit yourself. (Offers him a drink but Sunny denies). More for me then.
Sunny: The River King says you were the only survivor of a massacre. 
Old man: Well, ***there goes my buzz.*** What's it to you?
Sunny: I was also on that boat. 
Old man: You..... you were the boy. You were the one they were after.

I think it's enough context.
Could you please tell me the meaning of emboldened phrase?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "[buzz](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/buzz#Noun) (sense 4)" is feeling of excitement, happiness, or slight drunkeness.

So "There goes my buzz" is a comment meaning "my buzz has gone".  It has been used because Sunny has just asked about the massacre.  Before that the old man was happy or excited.  Now, because he is thinking about the massacre he feels sad or glum. So he makes a comment about his "buzz".

It is very casual, but quite natural for a person like an old man, but it would be hard for a learner to make it sound natural.  It is unusual to have a situation in which it is an appropriate thing to say, as it can imply blame for making someone unhappy, but in a highly casual way.

Answer (score 1):

The implication is that the old man is drinking alcohol. When you've had some alcohol--like 2 to 3 drinks--but before you're drunk, that state is sometimes called a "buzz."

Now that Sunny reveals that the conversation is about an unhappy occasion, the old man is saying that he's lost the pleasant feeling of being a little bit inebriated.

Answer (score 1):

a "buzz" refers to a euphoric feeling experienced after doing drugs or smoking cigarettes; depending on the drug taken, the user can experience a buzz (or a high) for a varied period of time, Now there are factors that can enhance or ruin the buzz, for instance if you're chilling out with your buddies smoking some weed and your dad barges in, that could potentially ruin your buzz or the pleasant feeling you've been experiencing